# icvOpenAVI_XINE() error in VideoCapture Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, ffmpeg, ip-camera

I'm trying to connect my ip-camera with OpenCV 2.4.5 in Python 2.7 with this function `cap=cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.180.60:82/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=")` , but It gives me this error:

```
input_bluray: (bluray_class_get_instance:1455) bluray_class_get_instance
input_bluray: (bluray_class_get_instance:1455) bluray_class_get_instance
demux_wavpack: (open_wv_file:127) open_wv_file: non-seekable inputs aren't supported yet.
(ERROR)icvOpenAVI_XINE(): Unable to open source 'http://192.168.180.60:82/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd='
```

In [this forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1076793&page=2) they discuss about the icvOpenAVI_XINE error as an ffmpeg problem with the --enable-shared flag, I did that a lot of times, and the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to avoid this error without change anything in OpenCV. The solution is described as follows:
1. Install vlc:  sudo apt-get install vlc
2. By command line write this script:  `vlc "http://192.168.180.60:82/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=" --sout "#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/output.mpeg},dst=display}" --sout-keep`  where http:// 192.168.180.60:82/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd= contains my Ip-camera streamming and rtsp://:8554/output.mpeg is the output created by VLC
3. Call the streaming using OpenCV using this function: `cap=cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://:8554/output.mpeg")`